# Rails not assigning a value for "created_at" attribute or for "id."

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to programming and have been learning Ruby on Rails for about 10 weeks. In the Rails console, whenever I create a new instance of one of my models, all attributes come up nil:

```
2.0.0-p576 :002 > List.create
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<List id: nil, name: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Isn't Rails supposed to generate List id and created_at automatically when I create the model instance?
Hereis my schema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141124011011) do

  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "body"
    t.integer  "list_id"
    t.boolean  "done",       default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "items", ["list_id"], name: "index_items_on_list_id"

  create_table "lists", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "lists", ["user_id"], name: "index_lists_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

I know this should be a simple question and I have searched for a while now for an answer, but haven't come up with anything. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the model:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items

  validates :name, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

I added values to list name and user so that it would pass validation, but I'm still having the same problem.

```
2.0.0-p576 :001 > list = List.create(name: "Grocery List", user: User.first)
  User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<List id: nil, name: "Grocery List", user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Comment: Can you show us the model? Looks like the model is failing validation. If that is the case, then what you're seeing is correct, because the object hasn't been persisted yet (the clue is the `rollback transaction` part). You can also do `test = List.create`, followed by `test.errors` to see what validation errors exist.

Comment: Ok - just added the model.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, the problem you're seeing is because your object is failing validation. The clue in the log is the `rollback transaction`; that usually indicates some kind of exception that prevented the object from persisting.

That explains the lack of `id` and `created_at` values. Since the object never persisted, those values were never able to be set.

In your case, you've got two validators:

```
validates :name, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
validates :user, presence: true
```

As is probably clear from those lines of code, both `name` and `user` need to be populated, and `name` must be at least 5 characters long.

So you'll have to do something like this instead:

```
list = List.create(name: "list_name", user: User.first)
```

Note: `User.first` can be replaced with any user object, it is merely for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so I added a name and a user, but for some reason I'm still having the same problem (I added my Rails console actions above). I ran the test you suggest and got this: 2.0.0-p576 :004 > test.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x9b6291c @base=#<List id: nil, name: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:name=>["is too short (minimum
is 5 characters)", "can't be blank"], :user=>["can't be blank"]}>
2.0.0-p576 :005 >

Comment: @EricLowber Strange, its still failing validation. Can you show me the exact creation line you executed?

Comment: Yes, 2.0.0-p576 :001 > list = List.create(name: "Grocery List", user: User.first)

Comment: @EricLowber Very strange. I assume that's the full `List` code you posted? You don't have any `before_save` filters or anything that could alter the values before saving? I suppose you could try the old hash syntax `list = List.create(:name => "Grocery List", :user => User.first)`. You're using ruby 2.0, so that shouldn't make a difference though. You could also be explicit about the syntax and include the curly braces, and do `List.create({name: "Grocery List", user: User.first})`; again I'd be surprised if that made a difference but give it a shot, just to rule out possibilities.

Comment: @EricLowber Additionally, does it make any difference if you do `list = List.new(name: "Grocery List", user: User.first)`, and then `list.save`?